# Editing Images, Image_titles, Image_description from a post with multiple images

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hi Djangonauts,
                  I have a created a post with multiple images. it works perfectly fine but when I try to edit the post with multiple images I get a AttributeError. image of the error message posted below at the end of the question. below are my 
    **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    post_image = models.ImageField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                           'slug': self.slug})

class Prep (models.Model): #(Images)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_prep')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True, default='')
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    image_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title + " Image"
```

now I have successfully created the **post_create** as you can see below this work perfectly fine and adds multiple images to my post, along with image_title and image_description

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Prep, fields=('image', 'image_title', 'image_description'), extra=7)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
            for f in formset.cleaned_data:
                try:
                    photo = Prep(post=instance, image=f['image'], image_title=f['image_title'], image_description=f['image_description'])
                    photo.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            return redirect('posts:single', username=instance.user.username, slug=instance.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Prep.objects.none())
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)
```

but my post_edit view is giving me an error see image below the code to see the image of error message. Below is my code for **post_edit**

```
def post_edit(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Prep, fields=('image', 'image_title', 'image_description'), extra=7, max_num=7)
    if post.user != request.user:
        raise Http404()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
            data = Prep.objects.filter(post=post)
            for index, f in enumerate(formset):
                if f.cleaned_data:
                    if f.cleaned_data['id'] is None:
                        photo = Prep(post=post, image=f.cleaned_data.get('image'), image_title=f.cleaned_data.get('image_title'),
                                     image_description=f.cleaned_data.get('image_description'))
                        photo.save()
# I believe the code below this the "elif" and "else" part may have some error but can't seem to find where the problem is
                    elif (f.cleaned_data['image'], f.cleaned_data['image_title'], f.cleaned_data['image_description']) is False:
                        photo = Prep.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))
                        photo.delete()
                    else:
                        photo = Prep(post=post, image=f.cleaned_data.get('image'), image_title=f.cleaned_data.get('image_title'),
                                     image_description=f.cleaned_data.get('image_description'))
                        d = Prep.objects.get(id=data[index].id)
                        d.image=photo.image,
                        d.image_title=photo.image_title,
                        d.image_description=photo.image_description
                        d.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = PostEditForm(instance=post)
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Prep.objects.filter(post=post))
    context = {'form': form, 'post': post, 'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'posts/post_edit.html', context)
```

Below is the error message I am getting if I try to edit my post which has multiple Prep images. .   , [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try edit your codes in these lines;
you add commas at the end, Python considers this behavior as tuple

```
d = Prep.objects.get(id=data[index].id)
d.image=photo.image #, # remove comma
d.image_title=photo.image_title #, # remove comma
```

For the `elif` clause:
instead of `Variable is False`, do this `not Variable`

```
elif not f.cleaned_data['image'] or not f.cleaned_data['image_title'] or not f.cleaned_data['image_description']:
    photo = Prep.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))
    photo.delete()
```

Comment: awesome this did the job, I am now able to edit the images, However the elif clause is still not working. I cannot remove a image once I add it. but now I can replace it with another image.

Comment: Just tried

                    `elif f.cleaned_data['image'] is False or f.cleaned_data['image_title'] is False or f.cleaned_data['image_description'] is False:


                        photo = Prep.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))
                        photo.delete()`


I thought it will work but it didn't

Comment: I am so sorry, I hoped it would work but it brings me to the same form again,
I clear the image_title
I clear the image_description
and I check on the image clear radio button
and hit submit
It brings me to the same form. The image is gone, but I get a error saying Image_title and Image_description are required. Usually upon successful execution it should take me back to the post


I get the same above error in all my attempts too

Comment: I think maybe, its not the `elif` statement that is wrong maybe something is wrong with the statement after the `elif` clause

`photo = Prep.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))` I use slug for Post and id for Prep. so usually if I have to call for post object I use `post.slug`  and for prep object I use `prep.id`